# Javascript return array from 2 arrays removing duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, duplicates, javascript-objects

Searched and tried and no luck so far.

```
var newUsers = [{name: 'rich', id: 25}, {name: 'lauren', id: 35}, {name: 'dave', id: 28} ]

var likedUsers = [{name: 'derek', id: 39}, {name: 'rich', id: 25}, {name: 'brian', id: 38} ]
```

What I want returned is:

```
var leftUsers = [{name: 'lauren', id: 35}, {name: 'dave', id: 28} ]
```

basically without the `rich` object as this is a duplicate. I only care about the `id` key.

I have tried:

```
newUsers.forEach((nUser) => {
    likedUsers.forEach((lUser) => {
        if (nUser.id !== lUser.id){
            leftUsers.push(nUser)
        }
    })
})
```

but obviously this won't work as this will just add them all as soon as they don't match.

if possible would like an es6 solution using forEach/map/filter

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge two arrays in JavaScript and de-duplicate items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items)

Comment: @SergeK. well no coz this concerns objects, and 2 why are you downvoting me?

Comment: So, what happened to brian? You want only the items in `new` that __aren't__ in `liked`?

Comment: The logic is the same... You just have to change `a[i] === a[j]` to `a[i].myProp === a[j].myProp`. You could also find lot of example all over the internet.

Comment: first merge it into one array, then loop it and save the ids in a new array var. always check the id doesnt exists in this new array and if it exists delete it on the merged one

Comment: @David could you make that more convoluted please?

Comment: You want ES6? Replacing your `var` with `const` would be a start!

Comment: @SteeveDroz Maybe those arrays aren't constants ? OP could _need_ to use `var`. Hard to tell without context.

Comment: They use `let`. BTW, they are constant as long as they are not replaced by something else (`newUsers = ...`). If they are edited (things are added, removed or edited from the list), they are still considered "constant" because their *reference* doesn't change. `const` doesn't mean unmodifiable in JS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `array.prototype.filter` to filter out items that exists in `likedUsers` and `array.prototype.findIndex` to check the existence, it should be:

```js
var newUsers = [{name: 'rich', id: 25}, {name: 'lauren', id: 35}, {name: 'dave', id: 28} ];
var likedUsers = [{name: 'derek', id: 39}, {name: 'rich', id: 25}, {name: 'brian', id: 38} ];

var leftUsers = newUsers.filter(u => likedUsers.findIndex(lu => lu.id === u.id) === -1);

console.log(leftUsers);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `filter()` and `some()` methods.

```js
var newUsers = [{name: 'rich', id: 25}, {name: 'lauren', id: 35}, {name: 'dave', id: 28} ]
var likedUsers = [{name: 'derek', id: 39}, {name: 'rich', id: 25}, {name: 'brian', id: 38} ]

const result = newUsers.filter(e => !likedUsers.some(a => a.id == e.id));
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var newUsers = [{name: 'rich', id: 25}, {name: 'lauren', id: 35}, {name: 'dave', id: 28} ];
var likedUsers = [{name: 'derek', id: 39}, {name: 'rich', id: 25}, {name: 'brian', id: 38} ];

var leftusers = newUsers.filter( item => !likedUsers.find(item2 => item.id == item2.id));

console.log(leftusers);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) of ids that are found in `likedUsers`, and [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the `newUsers` by checking if an id is in the Set:

```js
const newUsers = [{name: 'rich', id: 25}, {name: 'lauren', id: 35}, {name: 'dave', id: 28} ]
const likedUsers = [{name: 'derek', id: 39}, {name: 'rich', id: 25}, {name: 'brian', id: 38} ]

const result = newUsers.filter(function({ id }) {
  return !this.has(id) // take all users which ids is not found in the set
}, new Set(likedUsers.map(({ id }) => id))) // create a set of ids in likedUsers and assign to this

console.log(result)
```